# how to develop Beam Pipeline locally on IDE and run on Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

how to develop Beam Pipeline locally on IDE and run on Dataflow? 
I want to use pycharm in my PC to develop Beam pipelines and run them on Dataflow. Are there any tutorials on how to do this?

Comment: You can develop it locally and send it to the Dataflow service for execution via the "--runner=DataflowRunner" pipelineoption argument. Check the Google Dataflow doc for more info: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python

Switching to "DirectRunner" executes the pipeline locally, which will make debugging and development easier.

Comment: Gindele- can I run it locally with "direct Run" instead of run it on Google cloud dataflow service ?

Comment: Yes, setting --runner=DirectRunner will run it locally.

Comment: Gindele- I can run it locally with local file successfully for wordcount example. and when connect to gs ,also success with the way to connect to BG： by ping:gcloud auth application-default login in the cloud SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Set the parameter as : 
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params

and try example as:
https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_minimal.py

Answer (score -1):

Its easy.

1. Step-1 Code Stuff as a .py file
2. In Terminal just run the .py file